# How to find the % Contribution of a Change of Terms within a Cube Root?

Tags: radicals

How do you find the contribution of an increase of each term within a cube root?

Given that:
$$result = \sqrt[3]{a*b*c}$$

Looking at how the result changes from say t0 to t1:

$$result_0 = \sqrt[3]{a_0*b_0*c_0}$$

$$result_1 = \sqrt[3]{a_1*b_1*c_1}$$

I want to know how the change in each term affects the change in the result.

$(a_1-a_0)$ contributed ___% to the change $(result_1-result_0)$

$(b_1-b_0)$ contributed ___% to the change $(result_1-result_0)$

$(c_1-c_0)$ contributed ___% to the change $(result_1-result_0)$

e.g. Let’s say $(a_1-a_0) > (b_1-b_0) > (c_1-c_0)$

Obviously then the change in a $(a_1-a_0)$ contributes a larger percentage than the change in b $(b_1-b_0)$ and in c $(c_1-c_0)$ to the change in the result characterized by $(result_1-result_0)$

Is it just $\frac{(a_1-a_0)}{(a_1-a_0) + (b_1-b_0) + (c_1-c_0)}$?

Also: what if, say, $(c_1-c_0)$ is negative? How does that affect the calculation?

Thanks very much!

**EDIT - To Clarify My Question**

Let's JUST SAY, between two periods of time:

a is running ability, b is swimming ability, c is climbing ability

result is overall athletic ability

$$\sqrt[3]{0.408*0.405*0.754} = 0.499= athleticability_0$$

$$\sqrt[3]{0.739*0.631*0.861} = 0.738 = athleticability_1$$

$$(athleticability_1-athleticability_0) = 0.239$$
$$(run_1-run_0) = 0.331$$ 
$$(swim_1-swim_0) = 0.226$$ 
$$(climb_1-climb_0) = 0.107$$
So my overall athletic ability increased by 0.239 because running ability increased by 0.331, swimming ability increased by 0.226, and climbing ability increased by 0.107. Does that imply:

$$\frac{(0.331)}{(0.331) + (0.226) + (0.107)} = 0.498 $$

Improvement to running ability accounted for 49.8% of that athletic ability improvement of 0.239?

(And so, using same method of calculation, increases in swimming ability accounted for 34.0% and increase in climbing ability accounted for 16.1%?)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Use MathJax for math formatting-http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: you want to calculate the partial and total differential of $u(a,b,c)$ at the point $(a_0,b_0,c_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more complex. The increment of the result depends also from the initial values, $a,b,c$

For instance, consider $\sqrt[3]{8\cdot 20\cdot 50}=20$

Increment the numbers by $2,3,4$ to get $\sqrt[3]{10\cdot 23\cdot 54}\approx 23.1583$

Now consider $\sqrt[3]{2\cdot 10\cdot 12}\approx 6.21447$

and apply the same increments. We get $\sqrt[3]{4\cdot 13\cdot 16}\approx 9.40534$

As you can see percentages are very different.

If you want to understand further in a easier way, start with only one variable, like $\sqrt[3]{x}$

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I added an example to my question to clarify what I mean. The concept I'm trying to address seems really straightforward but I don't know how to verify it.